# Why does my Windows Service stop?

Tags: c#, windows-services

My Windows service runs briefly, and then stops (no err msg).

I have this code in Program.cs of my Windows service:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread] 
    static void Main()
    {
        #if(!DEBUG)
        var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new RoboRprtrService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #else
        var rrs = new RoboRprtrService();
        rrs.ConfigureService();
        Console.ReadLine();
        #endif
    }
}
```

The breakpoint here:

```
var rrs = new RoboRprtrService();
```

...is hit (the DEBUG constant is currently defined), and so is the call to "InitializeComponent()" in my ServiceBase class, which is as follows:

```
public partial class RoboRprtrService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer;
    private bool operationIsRunning;

    public RoboRprtrService()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // <= Breakpoint here; is reached
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureService(); // <= Breakpoint here, not hit
    }

    public void ConfigureService()
    {
        const int ONE_HOUR = 3600000;
        timer = new Timer { Interval = 50000 };
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Tick;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        RoboRprtrLib.WriteToLog("RoboRprtrService has started");
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eeargs)
    {
        if (operationIsRunning) return; // <= Breakpoint here, not hit
        operationIsRunning = true;
        timer.Elapsed -= timer_Tick;
        try
        {
            RoboRprtrLib.WriteToLog("Timer tick event has occurred");
            RoboRprtrLib.GenerateAndSaveDueReports();
            operationIsRunning = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Tick;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        RoboRprtrLib.WriteToLog("RoboRprtrService has stopped");
    }    
}
```

When I step (F11) into the InitializeComponent(); in the constructor, it takes me to this machine-generated code:

```
namespace RoboReporterService
{
    partial class RoboRprtrService
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.ServiceName = "Service1";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

...(into the InitializeComponent() method) and then the Service stops.

Why does my service fail to "stay alive"?

As a side note, this project's properties, on the Application tab, show the output type of this as "Windows Application"; shouldn't it be "Class Library"?

### UPDATE

Note: If I call code from the ConfigureService() method in the Service class, like so:

```
public void ConfigureService()
{
    const int ONE_HOUR = 3600000;
    timer = new Timer { Interval = 50000 };
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Tick;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    RoboRprtrLib.WriteToLog("RoboRprtrService has started");
    operationIsRunning = true;
    RoboRprtrLib.GenerateAndSaveDueReports();
    operationIsRunning = false;
}
```

...it runs; but then the service stops, and the timer_Tick() handler is never reached, even though it is hooked up in ConfigureService()

Comment: In the exception settings, do you have *all* CLR exceptions enabled?  If you do, then you can run your service in debug mode and when an exception occurs, the service will stop and highlight the offending line of code.  You'll have to modify your `Program.cs` to call `Start` on your service directly, but presumably you've got an exception happening that you aren't observing.  I usually check for a `"-debug"` argument, and if it's present, I just start the service explicitly instead of calling `ServiceBase.Run`.

Comment: Exception settings where? I thought it was already in DEBUG mode; I have that checkbox checked in the project Properties > Build > Define Debug Constant checkbox

Comment: (1) Your code doesn't seem to call OnStart() so no surprise that that breakpoint isn't being hit.  (2) I assume that for debugging purposes you are launching your program from the debugger, not actually as a service?  (3) I suspect that timers don't work when Console.ReadLine is running, though I'm not sure about that.  Sounds like you're not getting that far anyway.  (4) You have a Main() function so the project is definitely an application, not a library.